# Get the right series for ttr function

Tags: r, quantmod

I got a few examples from TTR documentation like:

```
data(ttrc)

mfi <- MFI(ttrc[,c("High","Low","Close")], ttrc[,"Volume"])

data(ttrc)
price <- ttrc[,"Close"]

data(ttrc)
macd <- MACD( ttrc[,"Close"], 12, 26, 9, maType="EMA" )

data(ttrc)
ema.20 <- EMA(ttrc[,"Close"], 20)
```

Is `data(ttrc)` a data-dummy or what?
I want to use

```
getSymbols("AAPL",src="yahoo")
```

for the Series and select the right column from it like 'close' or 'volume'

"series that is coercible to xts or matrix"
How do I transform the timeseries from `getSymbols` to right matrix to use the examples from the documentation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual, `?ttrc`, confirms that the data is random.

You can extract the columns you want with the `Ad`, `Vo`, etc. functions or directly with square brackets.

```
tail( MACD(Ad(AAPL)) )
tail( MACD( AAPL[,"AAPL.Adjusted"] ) )
```